# Не работает терминал на Rapsberry

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

На Raspberry стоит Buster lite. Сделал режим киоска, чтоб только браузер работал, путём добавления открытия браузера с конкретной страницей в автозагрузке. Но не получается открыть терминал ни клавишами ctrl+alt+T ни ctrl+alt+1,2,3 и т.д. Если нажать ctrl+alt+7 он обновляет окно браузера. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл свою ошибку. У меня было в файле /boot/cmdline.txt было прописано `fbcon=map:2` 
когда убрал, всё заработало нормально

Answer (score 0):

Режим киоска подоразумевает невозможность выйти за пределы браузера.
Попробуйте, например, подключиться к raspberry через ssh.